# Assigning non registered users as students to course content type

Tags: users, entities

I have a content type course and I need to assign students ( nonregistered users ) to its nodes.

My students list contains only the names of students. I have tried [signup](https://www.drupal.org/project/signup) module and [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module but both of them need the user to be a registered user.

Though [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module provides a way where I can create registrations, but an email is required.

My objective is to store the student names with each course and I can later  output the total number of students associated to a course node using views.

Any clues on this ?

Comment: If students aren't users, don't use the User entity - use something else (like a node) to represent them. Then you can just use an entity reference field like normal

Comment: students as nodes, nice idea. I have many course nodes and many students need to be added to them. Can I just somehow copy paste students names in a Textarea and the nodes get created automatically ?

Comment: I doubt it, you'll probably need a more nuanced approach. Something like [Multi Node Add](https://www.drupal.org/project/multi_node_add) might help

Comment: Output your student names etc with a view. Copy that over into a csv file and import via https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds. BTW looked at @Clive 's approach above and it seems like a good one.

Comment: thanks, yes working on it, it might be the solution .